# Chef Solo in Vagrant: How to create RabbitMQ virtual host nad bind it to given username

Tags: vagrant, rabbitmq, chef-solo

I have a virtual machine created in Vagrant (a simple `hashicorp/precise64`). I need to provision it with RabbitMq and I would:

- Create username `testUsr` with `testPass` as password with administration role
- Create a virtual host `testVirtualHost`
- Bind `testVirtualHost` to `testUsr`

This is my attempt:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
        chef.add_recipe "rabbitmq"

        chef.json = {
            'rabbitmq' => {
                'default_user' => 'testUsr',
                'default_pass' => 'testPass',
                'virtualhosts' => ['testVirtualHost'],
                'enabled_users' => [
                    { 
                        'name' => 'testUsr', 
                        'password' => 'testPass', 
                        'rights' => [{ 'vhost' => 'testVirtualHost', 'conf' => '.*', 'write' => '.*', 'read' => '.*' }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    end
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 15672, host: 15672, id: "rabbitmq"
end
```

The user and password is created but virtual host isn't. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an amended Vagrantfile based on your requirements:

```
  Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
      config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
        chef.add_recipe "rabbitmq::user_management"
        chef.add_recipe "rabbitmq::mgmt_console"
        chef.json = {
          'rabbitmq' => {
            'default_user' => 'testUsr',
            'default_pass' => 'testPass',
            'virtualhosts' => ['testVirtualHost'],
            'enabled_users' => [
              {
                'name' => 'testUsr',
                'password' => 'testPass',
                'rights' => [{ 'vhost' => 'testVirtualHost', 'conf' => '.*', 'write' => '.*', 'read' => '.*' }],
                'tag' => 'administrator'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      end
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 15672, host: 15672, id: "rabbitmq"
    end
```

Below are the changes and additions I made:

- Create username testUsr with testPass as password with administration role

For the testUsr to be an administrator, this user needed to be tagged with 'administrator' [permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html):

```
        'enabled_users' => [
          {
            'name' => 'testUsr',
            'password' => 'testPass',
            'rights' => [{ 'vhost' => 'testVirtualHost', 'conf' => '.*', 'write' => '.*', 'read' => '.*' }],
            'tag' => 'administrator'
          }
```

- Create a virtual host testVirtualHost

The change here was not to call the rabbitmq recipe but call the rabbitmq::user_management recipe instead:

```
chef.add_recipe "rabbitmq::user_management"
```

This recipe calls the rabbitmq recipe. Part of the [user_management](https://github.com/jjasghar/rabbitmq/blob/master/recipes/user_management.rb) code will create the testVirtualHost.

- Bind testVirtualHost to testUsr

You already had the code in place for this. The change was as above (calling rabbitmq::user_management recipe)

I also noticed that you were port forwarding to the rabbitmq management console. For the console to work you would need to enable the rabbitmq_management plugin as per [management](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html).

I added:

```
chef.add_recipe "rabbitmq::mgmt_console"
```

as the [mgmt_console](https://github.com/jjasghar/rabbitmq/blob/master/recipes/mgmt_console.rb) recipe manages that plugin.

You will now be able to access the management console via http://localhost:15672

Comment: Perfect. This do the Job... what if would add new queues? I've googlin around without success